# Solr search with contain

Tags: solr

If my search keyword is 'test,' then my document is 'testtesttest.' How can I get the result to show that the number of occurrences is 3 in Solr?"

Unfortunately, the result I am getting shows a term frequency of 0 in Solr when I use the query
`q= test` with the term function `termfreq(section_title_t,test')`.

Please help. Thank you

Comment: have you tried writing your query like this `q=*test*` ?

Comment: Hello Alexng, did you find the solution to this ? We are in a same situation, let us know, if you found a way around.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the result of termfreq() in the solr dashboard as a separate field, you can use the **fl=** syntax as specified here: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_3/function-queries.html

You can use the controls available in the SOLR dashboard to generate the URL for you.

**Query**

First of all you need to add a standard query. Look for the box on the dashboard that has the **q** above and add something similar to:

> section_title:'test'

**Fields to return**

Look for the box with **fl** and add something similar to below:

> _uniqueid, termfreq(section_title,'test')

Note I added a uniqueid to differentiate, but you would most likely change to title field or something.

**Sort**

This might not be strictly be necessary in your situation, but if you are using a broader search query, then you need to ensure the results with higher matches are displayed. In this situation, look for the **sort** box and add something similar to:

> termfreq(section_title,'test') desc

**Execute Query**

Now when you hit the Execute Query button, it will generate the correct URL with query specified. Yours should look something like this:

```
https://localhost:8983/solr/#/your_index/query?fl=_uniqueid%2C%20termfreq(section_title%2C%27test%27)&q=section_title%3A%27test%27&sort=termfreq(section_title%2C%27test%27)%20desc
```

**Working Example:**

Please see screenshot below demonstrating this working as per above.

[image]